# What is the difference between duration vs processing time vs batch duration in spark ui?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-ui

As the picture below, what's the difference between duration, batch duration and processing time in spark UI ?

thanks

[Spark UI Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zrhUe.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `batch duration` of 1 min tells you, that your Spark streaming application works in batches of 1 minute, meaning it plans an RDD every minute. You set this duration in your code when creating the SparkSession.

The `processing time` tells you that it took Spark 34 seconds to process all input data (provided as `input data size`).

The `duration` gives you an understanding of the time it took to finish a particular job within your application.

Answer (score 0):

Duration is wall clock. Processing time is the sum of all jobs durations.